# Finding solution of differential equation using DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, graphs-and-networks

**On solving this differential equation mathematica "shows system allocation memory" error. I want to find solution of f but not able to find that.**
DSolve[{f[0] == 1., Derivative[1][f][0] == 0., (f^[Prime][Prime])[Z] == (0.00078125 (1.11854*10^11 + 4.04174*10^11 f[Z]^2 - 3.08717*10^13 f[Z]^4 - 2.95452*10^11 f[Z]^6 - 1.06759*10^12 f[Z]^8))/(f[Z]^3 (8.7386*10^7 + 3.15761*10^8 f[Z]^2))}, {f[Z]}, {Z}]

Answer (score 1):

If a numerical solution is acceptable, one can use `NDSolve` or `NDSolveValue`, for example:

```
Zmax=5000;

sol=NDSolveValue[{
    f[0]==1.,
    f'[0]==0.,
    f''[Z]==(0.00078125 (1.1185410^11+4.0417410^11 f[Z]^2-3.0871710^13 f[Z]^4-2.9545210^11 f[Z]^6-1.0675910^12 f[Z]^8))/(f[Z]^3 (8.738610^7+3.15761*10^8 f[Z]^2))},
  {f[Z]},{Z,0,Zmax}];

Plot[sol,{Z,0,Zmax}]
```

[image]